# perl regex command line - how to get matches instead replacing

Tags: regex, perl, command-line

I am new with perl. And I would like to get the matches, instead replacing the text.

I there anyway to accomplish that using one line command?

Sample text I am using:
text.txt

```
sample1 other sample2 other
```

Command I am using:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/sample\d/changed/gs' text.txt
```

I would like to have the following output (using one line command):

```
sample1
sample2
```

I am using strawberry perl in Windows PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
perl -ne "while(/(sample\d)/g){print \"$1\n\";}" text.txt
```

This looks better I think:

```
perl -lne "while(/(sample\d)/g){print $1;}" text.txt
```

Comment: Any time you want to just find a pattern, use `/pattern/`. Use `s/pattern/string/` only when you really want to change it.