# Alternative to 'find' which supports PCRE

Tags: regex, perl, find, pcre

Linux's find command does not support Perl compatible regular expressions (PCRE).
Is there an alternative that can do that that is concise to use (one line on command line).

I found some one liners but they were long and complicated, making it difficult to understand what they do and a pain to write them every time.

Examples:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/726878/is-it-possible-to-use-perl-like-regular-expressions-with-the-linux-find-command

uses pipelining, -options, and multiple functions.

[Unix/Linux/FreeBSD Find Command with Perl Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894673/unix-linux-freebsd-find-command-with-perl-regex)

uses a lot of options and also Perl

I tried using Perl directly but didn't find a pure Perl one-liner for it.

Example:

[perl regex command line - how to get matches instead replacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55304227/perl-regex-command-line-how-to-get-matches-instead-replacing)

Gives a one liner for finding matches within a single file. But does not find filename matches within a directory.

Comment: This question needs more information. What do you wish to match regular expressions against? The file names or the file contents? Both? What did you try in Perl?

Comment: @tobyink
I want to match filename. I tried googling perl oneliners but only got scripts and complicated piping with linux commands. I want something that is simple interface so I don't need to learn what all the parameters are doing.

Comment: What are your criteria for the filename?

Comment: @zdim I don't have specific criteria right now. This is preparing for the future for if I need it. The only criteria I can think of right now are ones that can probably work with basic regular expressions (ex: filenames that contain various spellings of a specific substring), although I'm not sure what capabilities PCRE has over basic regular expressions

Comment: `find -exec grep -LP REGEXP {} +` will print the name of files that contain a line that matches `REGEXP`.

Comment: `find | grep -P REGEXP` will print the name of files that match `REGEXP`.

Comment: I tweaked the title to make it a bit clearer since I think that this is a useful question. (Indeed, why doesn't the grand `find` have better regex support?)  Shame that the question doesn't have (at least _some_ :) detail so to be viable, like some of those Perl one-liners or pipelines you looked into  etc

Comment: @zdim The message I get is that the question was closed for being off-topic. Which I don't understand since when I follow the link for what is on-topic I think this question fits. It is about a programming problem, software tools, and is practical and answerable. But I've added the pipeline and one-liner examples I looked into in case that helps, and submitted the question for review to reopen.

Comment: @roobee "_... was closed for being off-topic. Which I don't understand ..._"  -- I'd say that it's altogether because the question is a bit generic, and without showing attempts (code) etc.  Perhaps unfortunate to give the reason as "off topic."  It needed be more specific, like '_this is what I want and this is what i'm trying but this is what i'm (not) getting_...'.  You don't really want to back the question with links to other pages either but I find this good enough and I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Perl's [File::Find](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Find)

```
perl -MFile::Find -wE'find( sub { say $File::Find::name if /\.pl$/ }, q(.) )'
```

This finds all entries which end with `.pl`, recursively anywehere under the current directory.

Or take the directory as input, with the current dir as default

```
perl -MFile::Find -wE' $d = shift//q(.); 
    find( sub { say $File::Find::name if /\.pl$/ }, $d )' directory-name
```

Or assemble all files found for some possible post-processing, writing to file etc

```
perl -MFile::Find -wE' $d = shift//q(.); 
    find( sub { push @f, $File::Find::name if /\.pl$/ }, $d ); 
    say for @f'  directory-name
```

(If run without a directory-name then the current directory is used)

However, I don't see why a simple pipeline of `find` + `grep` isn't suitable.  The `grep` itself supports basic regex, while with `-E` it supports extended ones and with `-P` (Perl) it uses PCRE.  So

```
find ... | grep -P regex
```

does exactly what is asked, in one command line.  Criteria for filenames then can be split, some to go with `find`'s own globbing and some in `grep`'s regex.

---

Finally, the question asks for PCRE and `find` indeed doesn't have PCRE regex, as stated.  However, `find` does support other flavors of regex. The man page has only a basic statement while a detailed description of differences between the flavors can be found with `info find` command on Linux (what I couldn't find on internet).

In short, the main differences from PCRE as used by `grep` and other tools, are: 1) the regex pattern *has to match the whole path* and not just a substring in it, and 2) this is very basic

So to find a file which has letters and then numbers before a `.txt` extension in the filename, with anything else for the path, anywhere in or under the current directory

```
find . -type f -regex '.*\/[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+\.txt'
```

Note that the leading `.*` is necessary, otherwise the path leading to the filename itself can't be matched (there's at least `./` in it).

Basic as it is in comparison with the full PCRE, this may well be plenty enough for most uses.

Comment: I get "Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1."
probably because I have perl on windows

Comment: @roobee Ah -- on Windows double-quotes are delimiters for the program, `perl ... -wE" ... "` (not `' ... '`) -- and then instead of `"."` for the directory use `'.'` (or simply `q(.)`)

Comment: I changed quotes inside the program (`"."`) to an operator form of single quotes, `q(.)`.  For Windows youo still need to change overall quotes for the program, from `'...'` to `"..."`.  I don't do this often on Windows so am not sure whether there is any other such adjustment to make (I tested on Linux)

Comment: It's working. And if I replace \.pl$ with a different regexp it works. But there are a lot of words to type each time. Is there a solution where you just need a path and the regexp?

Comment: @roobee "_But there are a lot of words to type_" -- what do you mean?  Type the regex and give it a directory, that's it.  Or do you mean the "one-liner" itself?  Hopefully  you can copy-paste it?  There are no canned solutions (that I know of), this is still a specific request.  Perhaps on Windows there are, in fact; there is probably a lot of software which can find files using some form of  patterns.

Comment: @roobee I'd really recommend to write a little program -- just like this one-liner -- and then you can just call it.  If it's for your own use and there is no question of security then you can make it to take the regex as well, at invocation.  So you'd say `prog.pl dir regex`, or make it take proper options like `prog.pl -d dir -p regex` (`-p` for pattern), where you can then easily provide for long options as well (`--dir` as well as `-d` etc)

Comment: Yeah I mean the one-liner itself. I can copy-paste it now. But needing to store this command in a file, and opening the file to copy paste it everytime I use it in the future is inconvenient. I did try to find software that can find files using PCRE with a simple interface but I did not find any. That software was actually what I was requesting in my question.

Writing a program sounds like a good idea. I had been trying to avoid it because I don't know perl so I would need to invest time in learning how to do that. But it seems to be the best solution at this point.

Comment: Writing a program like this is simple but I'd be reluctant to post it cold as little tweaks are usually needed and if you don't know any language then the program need be far more carefully written and that adds up.  (Plus they closed the question real quick.)  But you can use `find` + `grep` pipeline (`find ... | grep -E ...`) -- that's not so complicated?  And `grep -E` accepts a decent regex

Comment: @roobee Re "*probably because I have perl on windows*', The question is tagged [tag:linux]

Comment: Thanks! The find grep pipeline works great.

Comment: @roobee Great :)  Note that `find` is loaded with options and capabilities

Comment: @roobee I couldn't help it and I added a note on `find`'s own `-regex` support.  It ain't PCRE but it is regex, way way better than the basic globbing and probably enough for many (most?) needs.